# Hide a tag and img if the checkbox is not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have some checkboxes in an overlay and as long as they are not checked the `<img>` and the `<a>` tag should not be seen.

HTML for the `<a>` and `<img>` tag:

```
<div id="extra">    
    <a href="detail.html?event=theater&datum=01_01" class = "theater">
        <img src="img/theater.png" alt="Theater">
    </a>
    <img src="img/literatur.png" alt="Literatur">
</div>
```

This is the checkbox:

```
<div class="tags">
    <label>
        <input  type="checkbox" rel="alles" id="checkme"/>
        Alles
    </label>
</div>
```

And this is the function:

```
$("#extra").css("display","none");
$("#checkme").click(function(){
    if ($("#checkme").is(":checked"))
    {
        $("#extra").show("fast");
    } else{
         $("#extra").hide("fast");
    }
});
```

I also tried some other ways but nothing helped.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/d48wLvoL/. Are you running your code via a document.ready call or at the end of the body?

Comment: What is your problem? your code also works http://jsfiddle.net/d48wLvoL/1/  . you may forget to include jquery file..

Comment: ok thats crazy ^^ because i tried it again and it doesnt worked but then i tried it another time and now it is working o.O

Answer (score 4):

This is more elegant in my opinion

```
$("#extra").hide();
$("#checkme").on("click",function(){
  $("#extra").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

I assume you do the above after the relevant objects have rendered, otherwise you need

```js
$(function() {
  $("#extra").hide();
  $("#checkme").on("click",function(){
    $("#extra").toggle(this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="extra">    
    <a href="detail.html?event=theater&datum=01_01" class = "theater">
        <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2711/free_icons_for_windows8_metro/128/theatre_masks.png" alt="Theater">
    </a>
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/itzikgur/my-seven/128/Books-2-icon.png" alt="Literatur">
</div>

<div class="tags">
    <label>
        <input  type="checkbox" rel="alles" id="checkme"/>
        Alles
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help even if i dont need it now ^^ since it is working

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yfnen44e/ has a working example. I am assuming you only wanted to hide the linked image in `#extra` and not the whole div.

```
var $extra = $('#extra a').hide();
$('#checkme').on('click', function (){
   $extra.toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this change:**  Your code put into `$(document).ready(function () {your code here});`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#extra").css("display", "none");
    $("#checkme").click(function () {
        if ($("#checkme").is(":checked")) {
            $("#extra").show("fast");
        } else {
            $("#extra").hide("fast");
        }
    });
});
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d48wLvoL/3/)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do this, one of which is using the jQuery **.prop** method to get the value of a property.

```js
  $("#checkme").click(function() {
    if ($("#checkme").prop('checked')) {
      $("#extra").show("fast");
    } else {
      $("#extra").hide("fast");
    }
  });
```

```css
#extra {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="extra">
  <a href="detail.html?event=theater&datum=01_01" class="theater">
    <img src="img/theater.png" alt="Theater" />
  </a>

  <img src="img/literatur.png" alt="Literatur" />
</div>
<div class="tags">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" rel="alles" id="checkme" />Alles</label>
</div>
```

**Note:** Using jQuery **.CSS** adds inline CSS to your document.